# "[object Object]" in Place of Variable Strings When Used in Alertify Prompts

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, alertify

I recently switched from regular JavaScript prompts to the jQuery Plugin 'Alertify' prompts. However, when I define a variable as the prompt's response, and use the variable in a later alert, it prints '[object Object]' instead. After a few hours of Googling and testing, I still haven't come up with an answer.

This is my code:

```
do {
    var fullLoop = false;
    var user = alertify.prompt("What is your name?", function (e, str) {
        if (e) {
            user.toUpperCase();
            if (str.length === 0) {
                alertify.alert("Please enter your name.");
                fullLoop = true;
            }
        } else {
            alertify.alert("Please enter your name.");
            fullLoop = true;
        }
    }, "Name");
    do {
        var bestLoop = false;
        var best = alertify.prompt("So " + user + ", what is your greatest ability, STRENGTH, SPEED, or SMARTS?", function (e, str) {
        if (e) {
            best.toUpperCase();
            if (best === "STRENGTH" || best === "SPEED" || best === "SMARTS") {
            var offset = options.indexOf(best);
            if (offset != -1) {
                options.splice(offset, 1);
            }
        } else {
            alert("Please choose either STRENGTH, SPEED, or SMARTS as your greatest ability.");
            bestLoop = true;
        }
        } else {
            alertify.alert("Please choose either STRENGTH, SPEED, or SMARTS as your greatest ability.");
            bestLoop = true;
        }
    }, "Greatest Ability");
    } while (bestLoop);
    alertify.alert("Great! So " + best + " is yor greatest ability.");
} while (fullLoop);
```

You can see the error I'm experiencing [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Gux22/58/).

I've also noticed that my `if` statements regarding the strings are ignored, I'm assuming there's a connection, but what is it? I haven't found any bugs, so am I using Alertify incorrectly?

Comment: as far as I can see, your usage of the plugin is wrong, the `var user = alertify.prompt("What is your name?", function (e, str)` does not return the entered user name, it returns an instance of the alertify object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your usage of the alertify plugin is wrong, it the prompt method is an asynchronous method and all the actions using that have to be done in the callback.

A minified version is as follows

```
var options = ["STRENGTH", "SPEED", "SMARTS"];
alertify.alert("Before we begin our journey, let's learn a little bit  about you.");

alertify.prompt("What is your name?", function (e, str) {
    if (e) {
        var  user = str.toUpperCase();

        alertify.prompt("So " + user + ", what is your greatest ability, STRENGTH, SPEED, or SMARTS?", function (e, str) {
            if (e) {
                var best = str.toUpperCase();
                if (best === "STRENGTH" || best === "SPEED" || best === "SMARTS") {
                    var offset = options.indexOf(best);
                    if (offset != -1) {
                        options.splice(offset, 1);
                    }
                    alertify.alert("Great! So " + best + " is yor greatest ability.");        
                } else {
                }
            } else {
            }
        }, "Greatest Ability");
    } else {
    }
}, "Name");
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/aDTBh/)

Comment: @weirdalexv: having issues running this for FF on OSX; however, Safari works --- be aware that this plugin is not well known and properly not thoroughly supported

Answer (score 0):

I don't know much about alterify, but it looks like you're trying to display a JSON object.  Try JSON.stringify(user) and see what you get.  It might be something like

```
{ "Name": "Paul" }
```

If so you'll then want to do

```
alertify.prompt("So " + user.Name + ", what is your greatest ability, STRENGTH, SPEED, or SMARTS?"
```

or maybe

```
alertify.prompt("So " + JSON.stringify(user.Name) + ", what is your greatest ability, STRENGTH, SPEED, or SMARTS?"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I tried both, and they just return undefined instead of [object Object]

Comment: Did anything happen with  alertify.prompt("So " + JSON.stringify(user) + ", what is your greatest ability, STRENGTH, SPEED, or SMARTS?"

Comment: Arun P Johny's method fixes the real issue, but thank you for your help anyways!